# Unable set Output file : Spring Batch Job

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am facing problem while running spring batch job.  I am confident about the batch job configuration as, the same was setup was working fine from last four days. I am attaching the snippet of stack trace generated while running the job.

Snippet 1:

```
2014-08-20 00:00:01,895 ERROR [STDERR] org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Unable to create file: [F:\jboss-4.2.3\config\feeds\jsdnmp\dailybillingfeeds\DailyBillFeed_jsdnmp_19-8-2014.csv]

2014-08-20 00:00:01,896 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.batch.item.util.FileUtils.setUpOutputFile(FileUtils.java:80)

2014-08-20 00:00:01,896 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter$OutputState.initializeBufferedWriter(FlatFileItemWriter.java:497)

2014-08-20 00:00:01,896 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter$OutputState.access$000(FlatFileItemWriter.java:354)

2014-08-20 00:00:01,896 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.doOpen(FlatFileItemWriter.java:291)

2014-08-20 00:00:01,896 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.open(FlatFileItemWriter.java:281)

2014-08-20 00:00:01,896 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor274.invoke(Unknown Source)

2014-08-20 00:00:01,897 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

Snippet 2: Caused by:

2014-08-20 00:00:01,900 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not delete file: F:\jboss-4.2.3\config\feeds\jsdnmp\dailybillingfeeds\DailyBillFeed_jsdnmp_19-8-2014.csv

2014-08-20 00:00:01,900 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.batch.item.util.FileUtils.setUpOutputFile(FileUtils.java:65)

2014-08-20 00:00:01,900 ERROR [STDERR]  ... 27 more
```

I have provided all access to the file for modification. This is output file location:

```
F:\jboss-4.2.3\config\feeds\jsdnmp\dailybillingfeeds\DailyBillFeed_jsdnmp_19-8-2014.csv
```

I have tried options using **appendAllowed** and **shouldDeleteIfExists**, but failed find any expected output.

Following information according to me may help you:

- Window 7
- Eclipse Helios
- Jboss 4.2 GA
- JDK 6

Comment: when you have appendAllowed on, does it actually append?

any chance you or someone else has a handle on the file? (aka has it opened, and therefore unable to delete?)  (only suggest this b/c you said it was working earlier)

Comment: No it does append. Finally I am getting exception. Could not overwrite.  Both keywords, I have added just to check after it dint work.

Answer (score 0):

please do these:

1. Add below plugin tag to your pom.xml so that all your maven dependencies will be copied to project/lib folder for every maven install command.

   ```
   <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <phase>install</phase>
           <goals>
             <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
             <outputDirectory>H:/workspace/JsonProject/lib</outputDirectory>
           </configuration>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
   ```
2. Then include all jars present in lib folder in project Build path.